# Can you customize what data is being collected for a Shopify customer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shopify

I'm looking into building an exercise logger on a pre-existing Shopify website. Ideally, I would like to link the user's customer profile with the exercise data being collected. Does Shopify allow you to do this and store the data on their servers somehow? Or would I have to store the data somewhere else like MongoDB? And would it even be possible to link the shopper account with an exercise logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A customer logged into a Shopify store has an ID. You can use that to store exercise data on your own server. Using the Shopify Admin API you can setup connections between the store and your database. Therefore you can indeed have code that would run, and allow you to Create, Read, Update or Delete any information you wanted, on a store.

Note however that due to a current weakness in Shopify App Proxy, it is possible (but unlikely) that a malicious actor could try impersonating a customer by trying random IDs till they got one that worked.